# Get value from JSON with grep

Tags: bash, grep

I have this line to read a value from a JSON string

```
ID=$(echo $ACCOUNT_REQ | grep -Po '"id": *\K"[^"]*"')
TYPE=$(echo $ACCOUNT_REQ | grep -Po '"type": *\K"[^"]*"')
```

The problem is that from time to time I get too much information read out.

```
id: ".........." instead of .......... (I get the double quotes too)
type: "NATIVE",
            "zoneTransferWhitelist" (I get the next part zoneTrans... too)
```

My shorted json

```
{
   "response":{
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"..........",
            "type":"NATIVE",
            "zoneTransferWhitelist":[
               
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How do I make it so that I only get the value between the quotation marks?

Comment: Move the `\K` after `"` and remove last `"`: `'"id": *"\K[^"]*'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew now i get: NATIVE FindZoneConfigsResult. EDIT: Vor the ID it works. Only for the Type I get "two values"

Comment: I would suggest to use https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ if possible.

Comment: The problem is in a docker container i don't have the jq

Comment: If it's your own image then you can install jq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant but you this works with your example and will get any single-line value from the json:

```
get_value() {
  echo "$1" | grep "\"$2\":" | sed "s/.*$2\":\"\(.*\)\",/\1/"
}
```

Then you can run:

```
get_value "$ACCOUNT_REQ" id
get_value "$ACCOUNT_REQ" type
```

The quotes around $ACCOUNT_REQ are important for keeping it split across multiple lines (assuming your initial json is multi-line like you've pasted above).